# Make table header and first two columns fixed

Tags: css

I am trying to make fixed table header and first two columns fixed. I am having trouble in making columns fixed (after scrolling right they columns are always displayed)
The current code I have makes table heading fixed and it works well, but I need columns # and Name fixed. Table is big, have many columns in the header.

```css
.tableFixHead {
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 600px;
}

.tableFixHead table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.tableFixHead th,
.tableFixHead td {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}

.tableFixHead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #eee;
}
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>01-11</th>
        <th>02-11</th>
        <th>03-11</th>
        <th>04-11</th>
        <th>05-11</th>
        <th>06-11</th>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Jack</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Michel</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Amanda</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: what you want not understand? Column `# and name` fixed so what was about other column?

Comment: When I am scrolling to right, they move and are shown always. The same with header when I am scrolling down header columns are shown always

Comment: what do you mean by `move`?

Comment: Eliminate the container `div` and give the <table> itself a fixed height,  `overflow:auto` and `display:inline-block`. Then the table headers will stick.

Comment: try this two link [sticky header](http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/fj8wM/),[sticky column](http://jsfiddle.net/DJqPf/7/)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```css
.tableFixHead {
  overflow: auto;
  height: 100px;
  width:300px;
}

.tableFixHead table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
}

.tableFixHead th,
.tableFixHead td {
  padding: 8px 16px;
}


td:first-child, th:first-child {
  position:sticky;
  left:0;
  z-index:1;
  background-color:white;
}
td:nth-child(2),th:nth-child(2)  { 
position:sticky;
  left:40px;
  z-index:1;
  background-color:white;
  }
.tableFixHead th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: #eee;
  z-index:2
}
th:first-child , th:nth-child(2) {
  z-index:3
  }
```

```html
<div class="tableFixHead">
  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>#</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>01-11</th>
        <th>02-11</th>
        <th>03-11</th>
        <th>04-11</th>
        <th>05-11</th>
        <th>06-11</th>
        </th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>Jack</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>Michel</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Amanda</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>Amanda</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
        <td>Y</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

I edited your code. ¿is this what you are looking for?